# JS storefront URL is picked up for OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE"

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Running into very strange situation with the Spartacus setup on CCV2. After setting up the meta placeholder in the index.html file:

I setup the baseURL as null in environment.ts and environment.prod.ts, just to be double sure.

baseUrl: null,

It seems to work, but the problem is when storefront is deployed, JS store is picking up the JS storefront URL for content load

`https://JS Storefront URL/XXXwebservices/v2/SITE/cms/pages`

My understanding is that it should be ACC Storefront URL:

`https://ACC Storefront URL/XXXwebservices/v2/SITE/cms/pages`

Is there any other setting that needs to be made? Other than the ones identified above? do we need any other configuration on the CCV2 side of things?

Answer (score 1):

The initial answer below didn't make too much sense, let me retry:

I recommend to leave out the baseUrl in the configuration completely, as the current behaviour prioritises the configuration over the meta-tag. See https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5886 for more info.

<s>While the `MEDIA_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE` has been added in Spartacus to distinguish the api and media, CCv2 has not yet implemented this feature. See also https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/2212#issuecomment-490089609.</s>

This is why the Spartacus side of it works, but the media base Url doesn't get injected on ccv2.

Comment: Not related to Media. This is for the Base URL setting. Spartacus is still pointing to itself rather than API service.Sample storefront you guys have
https://spartacus.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/
Pages are loaded from the API aspect of CCV2
https://api.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics-spa/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=homepage
In my case page load is pointing to JS Storefront URL not API. Just wondering if there is any setting for it?

Comment: ohw.. right. I read "media placeholder" ;) I've updated my answer.